# How to show unused use's in Eclipse for PHP?

Tags: eclipse, zend-studio

Some of use's is not required and I want my Eclipse ide to show this as warning. 
Which setting sholud I change?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the free tool **[PHP-CS-Fixer](https://github.com/fabpot/PHP-CS-Fixer).** It includes the [UnusedUseStatementsFixer.php](https://github.com/fabpot/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/master/Symfony/CS/Fixer/UnusedUseStatementsFixer.php) that will detect and remove all unused use statements.

It is also contained in the Eclipse plugin [PDT Extensions](http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org). Once installed, you can start it by right-clicking the PHP file in Eclipse. Options can be set at:

```
Eclipse -> Preferences -> PHP -> Code Style -> CS Fixer
```

That plugin works with Eclipse Kepler (4.3).

Comment: Thank you for answer but I don't want to run this tool after I wrote a code. I want my ide show unused imports.

Comment: CS-Fixer can be installed as Eclipse plugin, see my updated answer.